# If current page has URL variable of ?e=1 then use javascript to display an alert

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `PHP` page which redirects to a HTML page. I want to append a URL variable to the HTML page, and if the URL variable is `?e=1` (error = 1) then display an alert of `"Please choose at least one subscription."`.

I've tried this, but I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
               alert ('Please choose at least one subscription.')
       }
       return(false);
}
```

URL Example: http://www.example.com/index.html?e=1

Comment: It looks like you already have something that let's you get a value from the URL. Have you tried running `getQueryVariable('e')` and looking at what you get back?

Comment: @MikeC: `get back`?  They will get back `false`, always.

Comment: @SamAxe Not true. It will return `false` if it doesn't find the value in the URL. See: `if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}`

Comment: oi.  I hate that syntax style.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've put the `alert` after the `return`, so it's unreachable when the parameter matches -- and it's outside the `if` statement so it'll alert on every parameter that *doesn't* match.  It belongs here instead:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){
             alert ('Please choose at least one subscription.')
             return pair[1];
           }
   }
   return(false);
}
```

Or, better, remove the alert from that function and handle it based the return value, in case you later want to use this function for a different url parameter:

```
if (getQueryVariable('e')) { // or if (getQueryVariable('e') == 1) {...}
  alert("Please choose at least one subscription.");
}
```